# How to convert ImageButton custom class to ImageButton

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I use class java to custom circle image button. Now i want convert it to ImageButton. But give me error ClassCastException. I need help !
If you have resolve please give me.
Thanks.

I use

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Work ! but i want to ImageButton.

Java Code :

```
ImageButton btnPlay = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause1);
```

Code XML :

```
<android.tadev.blogradio.support.CircleButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/clear"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play1" />
```

Logcat

```
02-10 12:19:33.798: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 12:19:33.798: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.tadev.blogradio.support.CircleButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
02-10 12:19:33.798: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.tadev.blogradio.main.PlayBlog.onCreateView(PlayBlog.java:91)
02-10 12:19:33.798: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
02-10 12:19:33.798: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
02-10 12:19:33.798: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
02-10 12:19:33.798: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
02-10 12:19:33.798: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cast the object as `ImageButton`, rather use `CircleButton`.

As long as your CircleButton custom view extends ImageButton all the functionality of ImageButton will be present.

Use the following.

```
CircleButton btnPlay = (CircleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause1);
```

Comment: The solution has been given.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for that to fail is that CircleButton does not extends ImageButton. Otherwise you wouldn't get this error. Double check the exact package name of the ImageButton you are extending and the one you are casting to. You are missing some thing.

Comment: Oke.. thanks for help. @Duncan gave me an solution :)